# makefile match-anything as a prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile with four targets. Two of these targets can be duplicated so that there can possibly be many of them that are required to run as prerequisites (they are [double-colon targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html)). Two of the targets are [match-anything rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html). Unfortunately, it's not working at all like I'd expect it to. I started with this:

```
.PHONY:
build_%: pre_build post_build _internal_%
        @echo "4. $@: $^"

.PHONY: pre_build
pre_build::
        @echo "1. $@: $^"

.PHONY: _internal_%
_internal_%:
        @echo "2. $@: $^"

.PHONY: post_build
post_build::
        @echo "3. $@: $^"
```

That gave me this output:

```
make build_foo
1. pre_build: 
3. post_build: 
2. _internal_foo: 
4. build_foo: pre_build _internal_foo post_build
```

If I am explicit about prereqs, like this:

```
.PHONY:
build_%: pre_build post_build _internal_%
        @echo "4. $@: $^"

.PHONY: pre_build
pre_build::
        @echo "1. $@: $^"

.PHONY: _internal_%
_internal_%: pre_build
        @echo "2. $@: $^"

.PHONY: post_build
post_build:: _internal_%
        @echo "3. $@: $^"
```

Instead I get this:

```
make build_foo
1. pre_build: 
make: *** No rule to make target `pre_build'.  Stop.
```

What do I need to do to make a dependency work like this? I am using GNU Make 3.81.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a genuine bug in GNU Make 3.81.

I suggest this work-around:

```
define prebuild
@echo "1. pre_build: $^"
endef

define postbuild
@echo "3. post_build: $^"
endef

.PHONY:
build_%: _internal_%
        @echo "4. $@: $^"

.PHONY: _internal_%
_internal_%:
        $(prebuild)
        @echo "2. $@: $^"
        $(postbuild)

# pre_build and post_build are not used here, but may still be used elsewhere

.PHONY: pre_build
pre_build::
    $(prebuild)

.PHONY: post_build
post_build::
        $(postbuild)
```

Comment: This is really very close to what I'm looking for in that now things are executed in order. I updated the question to indicate that the desired goal is to be able to run multiple `pre_build` and `post_build` targets.

Comment: @paullckby: Can't you put their commands in `prebuild` and `postbuild`?